# for how How to compute whether representational similarity matrix values are significant

Tags: matlab, static-analysis, matlab-spm

I am new to RSA analysis in fMRI images. I used SPM 12 for preprocessing and first level analysis of my fMRI images and used RSA-toolbox to compute RDMs (representational dissimilarity matrix) for my conditions in an specific region of the brain. Now I have the RDM mateix for every single subject also have the overall RDM across all subjects. However, RSA-toolbox doesn't report any p value or significance test for the values in the RDM. How can I compute or determine which values in the RDM matrix are significant and which are not? I used pearson's r method for to compute RDMs. In paeticular I want to have an explaination about the mathematics that can be used to test significancy of these values.

Comment: This sounds rather like a question to understand a toolbox and the idea behind it than a programming question. Have you considered to write the developers of the RSA toolbox?

Comment: Actually this is a question about statistics. I want to know the math behind this statistical compuation regardless of the toolbox. I would like to know the concept of this statistical test and how we can compute p values for this test.